# Shared Memory Allocated Using "shm_open" and "ftruncate" Not as Specified

Tags: shared-memory

I am using the following code for understanding shared memory on Linux:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
        const char str1[] = "string 1";
        const char str2[] = "string 2";
        pid_t parpid = getpid(), childpid;
        int fd = -1;
        char *anon, *zero;

        if((fd = shm_open("/mmap_test", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR)) == -1)
                err(1, "shm_open");
        printf("created shared memory file\n");

        if(ftruncate(fd, 1024) != 0) err(1,"ftruncate");

        anon = (char*)mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANON|MAP_SHARED, -1, 0);
        zero = (char*)mmap(NULL, 1024, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);

        if (anon == MAP_FAILED)
                errx(1, "anon mmap");

        if (zero == MAP_FAILED)
                errx(1, "zero mmap"); 

        strcpy(anon, str1);
        strcpy(zero, str1);

        printf("PID %d:\tanonymous %s, zero-backed %s\n", parpid, anon, zero);
        switch ((childpid = fork())) {
        case -1:
                err(1, "fork");
                /* NOTREACHED */
        case 0:
                childpid = getpid();
                printf("PID %d:\tanonymous %s, zero-backed %s\n", childpid, anon, zero);
                sleep(3);

                printf("PID %d:\tanonymous %s, zero-backed %s\n", childpid, anon, zero);
                munmap(anon, 4096);
                munmap(zero, 1024);
                close(fd);
                return EXIT_SUCCESS;
        }

        sleep(2);
        strcpy(anon, str2);
        strcpy(zero, str2);

        printf("PID %d:\tanonymous %s, zero-backed %s\n", parpid, anon, zero);
        munmap(anon, 4096);
        munmap(zero, 1024);

        sleep(3);
        close(fd);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

My building command is given as follows:

```
g++ -lpthread -lrt mmap_test.cpp
```

where "mmap_test" is the name of my cpp file. In this code, the shared memory object is created by
`fd = shm_open("/mmap_test", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR)` and its size is modified by `ftruncate(fd, 1024)`. The file is mapped to a pointer in `zero = (char*)mmap(NULL, 1024, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);`.

Basically, I tried to modify the size of my shared object using `ftruncate`. I tried different sizes (1024 in the code is only one instance), and as I checked the file `/dev/shm/mmap_test`, I found it was always 4.0 KB, using the command `ls -sh /dev/shm/mmap_test`. I can only relate this 4.0 K to the page size on Linux. Can someone explain why the actual size is not as specified in the code?

Answer (score 1):

The object size is constrained by the granularity offered by the architecture and implemented in the kernel.   In your case, it appears that `4k` is that granularity; which would correspond to the base page size in x86 cpus.

Comment: Does it mean my shared memory can only be 4 K? Or is it that the actual memory can be larger than the size of this file? Actually I just modified all 1024 in my code to 8192, and the file size is still 4.0 KB.

Comment: It means that it can only *really* be a multiple of 4k.  You might make it 4k+1, and mmap 4k+1, but really you will get 8k.   You might be able to uncover this with `fstat(2)`, assume it with `sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE)` and the like.

Comment: Interesting. As I checked the size of file using fstat, while specifying 8192, its st_size is indeed printed as 8192. However, the file size shown from "ls -sh" is still 4.0 K. Seems to be a divergence.

Comment: I just realized that there is a difference between file logical size and file physical size. The divergence in sizes shown is from the difference between logical and physical sizes.